# Solving a mixed system of equality and inequality

Tags: r, sympy

**Intro:** I sucessfully use the [rSymPy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rSymPy/index.html) library to symbolically solve following example system of equalities.

x + y = 20; x + 2y = 10

```
library(rSymPy)
sympy("var('x')")
sympy("var('y')")  
sympy("solve([
  Eq(x+y, 20),     
  Eq(x+2*y, 10)
  ], 
  [x,y])")
# output
#[1] "{x: 30, y: -10}"
```

**Use case:** In my use case I want to **symbolically** solve a system of a mixed system of equality and inequality. Here's a reproduceable example:
x + y = 20; x + 2y > 10

The inequality can be sucessfully coded in rSymPy with `Gt`:

```
sympy("Gt(x+2*y, 10)")
# output
# [1] "10 < x + 2*y"
```

**Problem:** The code of the mixed system throughs an error:

```
sympy("solve([
      Eq(x + y, 20),     
      Gt(x+2*y, 10)
      ], 
      [x,y])")

# output    
# Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
#   Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "/Users/.../R/3.0/library/rSymPy/Lib/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 308, in solve 
#   raise NotImplementedError()
# NotImplementedError
```

**Question:** How can I refactor the code successfully to solve the mixed system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach using the [Rglpk](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://cran.r-project.org/package=Rglpk&ei=iqaiU8jIJI-B7QaGmIHYDA&usg=AFQjCNFWYpDWCnxPDJ1bvYjmkZpC1UZm5g&sig2=isRplxyCQItBrbEQIGiATA&bvm=bv.69411363,d.ZGU) library which can read in and solve GNU's [MathProg](https://www3.nd.edu/~jeff/mathprog/glpk-4.47/doc/gmpl.pdf) scripted problems in R:

```
# in case CRAN install does not work
install.packages("Rglpk", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")

library(Rglpk)

## read file
x= Rglpk_read_file("mathprog1.mod", type = "MathProg", verbose=T)

## optimize
Rglpk_solve_LP(obj= x$objective, 
               mat= x$constraints[[1]], 
               dir= x$constraints[[2]], 
               rhs= x$constraints[[3]], 
               bounds= x$bounds,
               types= x$types,
               max= x$maximum)
```

File `mathprog1.mod`:

```
# Define Variables
var x;
var y;

# Define Constraints
s.t. A: x + y = 20;
s.t. B: x + 2*y >= 10;

# Define Objective
maximize z: x + y;

# Solve
solve;
end;
```

R console output:

```
# $optimum
# [1] 20

# $solution
# [1]  0 20

# $status
# [1] 0
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Define a positive variable `z`. Then the system can be recast as a system of equalities in terms of `z`:

```
x <- Var('x')
y <- Var('y')
z <- Var('z')
sympy("solve( [ Eq(x+y, 20), Eq(x + 2*y - z, 10) ], [x, y] )")
```

giving:

```
[1] "{x: 30 - z, y: -10 + z}"
```

**2)** This is a linear programming problem so if you are just looking for any feasible solution to the constraints then the [lpSolve package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lpSolve) can provide such.  In this case it gives the solution corresponding to `z=10` in (1):

```
library(lpSolve)
out <- lp(, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2), 2), c("=", ">"), c(20, 10))
out$solution
## [1] 20  0
```

**ADDED** first solution in response to comment from poster.  Added some further discussion.

Comment: Thx, but a symbolical solution is required.

Comment: That's a nice trick. We should implement that in SymPy directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `NotImplmentedError` is coming form `SymPy` itself. It looks like it can't solve multivariate inequalities. It can only reduce them (which is what your example did). It doesn't appear that the library supports that type of system.

```
def _solve_inequality(ie, s, assume=True):
    """ A hacky replacement for solve, since the latter only works for
        univariate inequalities. """
    if not ie.rel_op in ('>', '>=', '<', '<='):
        raise NotImplementedError
    expr = ie.lhs - ie.rhs
    try:
        p = Poly(expr, s)
        if p.degree() != 1:
            raise NotImplementedError
    except (PolynomialError, NotImplementedError):
        try:
            n, d = expr.as_numer_denom()
            return reduce_rational_inequalities([[ie]], s, assume=assume)
        except PolynomialError:
            return solve_univariate_inequality(ie, s, assume=assume)
    a, b = p.all_coeffs()
    if a.is_positive:
        return ie.func(s, -b/a)
    elif a.is_negative:
        return ie.func(-b/a, s)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: In all honesty, any solution outside R language is beyond my limits. Thx, anyway - looks I got stuck with rSymPy for this specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I discovered the excellent [LIM package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LIM/index.html) which nicely allows symbolical solution to various kinds of linear inverse problems:

The ASCII file `linprog.lim` contains the symbolical problem in a human readable form (it's located in the same directory as the R code):

```
## UNKNOWNS
  X
  Y
## END UNKNOWNS

## EQUALITIES
  X + Y = 20
## END EQUALITIES

## INEQUALITIES
  X + 2 * Y > 10
## END INEQUALITIES

## PROFIT
  X + Y
## END PROFIT
```

Following R code provides the solution to the linear programming problem:

```
require(LIM)

model= Setup("linprog.lim")
model.solved= Linp(model, ispos=F, verbose=T)
model.solved
```

Output:

```
$residualNorm
[1] 3.552714e-15

$solutionNorm
[1] 20

$X
      X Y
[1,] 20 0
```